# undefined method `owners' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and i have stumbled upon a NoMethodError in my application which states that

> undefined method `owners' for nil:NilClass

I am trying to add new owners to my customer profile.. i have referenced both models as below

owner.rb

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
validates :customer_id, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :tel,     presence: true, length: { in: 7..10 }
before_save   :titlecase_name, :downcase_email
searchkick text_start: [:name], suggest: [:name]
def search_data
{
  name: name,
  tel: tel
}
end
```

owner_controller.rb

```
class OwnersController < ApplicationController

def create
  @owner = @customer.owners.build(owner_params)
  if @owner.save
    flash[:success] = "New owner added!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end

  private
    def owner_params
    params.require(:owner).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

customer_controller.rb

```
# customer profile page
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @owner = @customer.owners.build if logged_in?
  @owners = @customer.owners.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

new_owner_form.html.erb (rendered inside customer/show page)

```
<%= form_for(@owner, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "New owner name" %>
  </div>
    <%= f.submit "add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

migration file

```
class CreateOwners < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :owners do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :customer, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :owners, [:customer_id, :name]
  end
end
```

I tried to add new owners via the customer/show pages and such error occurred. I have checked my migrations several times and everything seems ok..

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass customer id in params to your create action and use it find the customer, you're getting this error because @customer is nil.

So you're doing something like this:

```
nil.owners.build(owner_params)
```

Your create action should be changed to this if you're in customers show action.

```
def create
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @owner = @customer.owners.build(owner_params)
  if @owner.save
    flash[:success] = "New owner added!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```